# Restoring Wordpress Header Image

Tags: header-image, theme-twenty-thirteen

Wordpress twenty thirteen theme. I have no idea how this arose. The opening page had a header image which started just beneath the green menu bar to just above the main central (yellow) text panel. Having noticed the image had gone, I tried to restore by going into customise and restoring the image. This only resulted in the image being displayed as a background image, not what I wanted.

Another page within the site shows another header image and how I want the front page to look:

https://www.isleofskyeaccommodation.com/skyespecialoffers.htm

The image I want on the front page is:

https://www.isleofskyeaccommodation.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/home-banner.jpg

The image size is 1366×650 whilst the recommended size is 1600×630. The image displayed previously in its entirety without cropping. Any ideas on how to restore the image on the front page?

Answer (score 0):

THe theme's Customizations area should allow you to specify the header image (and even the background image).

Although this is not the place to get support for a theme (or plugin), look in Customizations first (in Admin area, under Themes) to specify your header image.

It may be that the actual image file was deleted. You could tell by using the Developer Tools in your browser to see all the requests for the site. If the image file is part of the page code, but shows a 404 response, then the image file is missing from your site. Go into Customizations and re-add the header image.